# What is the standard when it comes to multiple pages in PyQT?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am making a simple app and was wondering what the standard is for multiple windows when using Qt Designer and python.

I need to be able to have functional back and next buttons which will take me to the previous screen like in simple .exe installers.

I do not want to use the tab widget.

I have tried using the stacked widget but when using layouts on my first screen it gets inserted into the grid layout.

[image: Like this]

Comment: Other than all the examples given in the other answers, give a look at the [QWizard](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwizard.html) framework too, which does exactly what you are describing.